# installing frapi on mamp?

Tags: php, mamp, frapi

Ok, so Frapi (http://getfrapi.com/) looks pretty cool. But for us non-server-gurus who just want to build an quick api for our client-side apps (the people who need stuff like frapi), the install docs at http://frapi.github.com/installing/index.html just look like greek? We use programs like MAMP for our server needs and if it doesn't have a Start/Stop button it's over our heads. Anybody know of a no-brainer tutorial on how to get Frapi running?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have Git Bash installed on your computer? If yes, just init and clone that repo into whatsoever www/path (If you didnt have Git installed, download the source manually), setting related directory and file permissions (CHMOD), add a standard virtualhost config (in your apache virtual host, in addition you can set the directive too), and you should can run it in a minutes.

Comment: I understood everything up until the virtualhost bit. I'm a UI junky. I don't CHMOD, I Apple+I, I don't scp, I Transmit... I understand what a virtual host is, I just don't know how to do it through MAMP. And I definitely don't know how to to configure Apache without MAMP. It seems MAMP pro is the answer for me... nice, easy UI.

Comment: `I understand what a virtual host is, I just don't know how to do it through MAMP` For that, check under your MAMP directory, apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf . There should be self explanatory and default structure of virtual host setting by default there (but you may need to uncommented `#`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame this was already answered, this looks very comprehensive:

[Avoid the madness when installing Frapi](http://blog.sossee.com/2013/05/04/avoid-the-madness-when-installing-frapi/)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the need to use the FRAP, but there was no possibility of setting up a virtualhost. So I download the tarball and make the changes needed to run the project without virtualhost.

The files are available for download at: http://www.felipemarques.com.br/2011/12/07/usando-frapi-video-demo-sem-configurar-virtualhost/

Att Felipe

Answer (score 0):

@toopay: Thanks, I found the conf file and you're right, it is pretty self explanatory from there.

I found, though, that for the incredibly lazy shelling out for MAMP Pro is the best answer. Though I have given up on Frapi.

Thanks.